# Can anyone tell me why this javascript function call isn't working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Here's a jsFiddle

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/irocmon/7WD8v/1/)

JavaScript:

```
 function createTable(tbody, rows, cols) {
     if (tbody == null || tbody.length < 1) return;
     for (var r = 1; r <= rows; r++) {
         var trow = $("<tr>");
         for (var c = 1; c <= cols; c++) {
             $("<td>")
                     .text("Table")
                     //.createElement("div")
                     .appendTo(trow);
         }
         trow.appendTo(tbody);
     }
 }   


$(document).ready(function() {
  createTable($("#table"), 4, 4);
});
```

HTML:

```
<table id="table" border="1">
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
----------------------------
<table id="table1" border="1">
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>

<br><br>
Select table size?
<form>
    <input type="button" value="4X4" onclick="createTable('table1', 4, 4)">
</form>
```

The JavaScript function called by JavaScript works fine(table), but the JavaScript function called by the OnClick isn't working(table1). Can you tell me why?

Also does anyone know why the `createElement("div")` isn't working either?

Comment: Thank you. I'm new to Stackoverflow, but it is without a doubt my favorite website now. I wasn't sure if the jsfiddle was enough, but now i know to also paste in my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed http://jsfiddle.net/7WD8v/6/

You needed to load you script in the head to have it available for that input

Comment: Yup! That did it! Thank you soo much! So it just can't reference it unless its put in the head? Which is where all my javascript goes in my website. I guess i should've just tried it. I thought jsfiddle would be easier to test it on.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `no wrap` in the fiddle and jQuery doesn't have `createElement` method (as you are calling it as a jQuery method). You may use [.append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

[Fiddle](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

Comment: Yup. That fixed it. So as far the div is concerned, what would i use there to create the div in every cell?

Comment: Use `.append("<div>test</div>")` instead of `createElement()`, I have added the code here http://jsfiddle.net/usmanhalalit/7WD8v/13/

Comment: Yes! That worked! You are awesome! Seriously! Thank you! This is the last piece to a part of my code that has taken weeks where even the simple things for some reason don't want to work. I'm so happy. I think this will finish it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/7WD8v/12/

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass the object on the onclick

```
createTable($('#table1'), 4, 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

Because on OnClick you pass a String as first argument value and in js call a collection of elements is passed.